If $\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t))=-|\nabla f(x(t))|^2$,$x(t)$ is bounded,standard arguments give that $\nabla f(\xi)=0$ at every accumulation $\xi$ of $x(t)$
I came across a paper where it was mentioned that "if
$
\frac{d}{dt} f(x(t)) = -|\nabla f(x(t))|^2
$
and $x(t)$ is bounded, standard arguments give that $\nabla f(\xi) = 0$ at every accumulation point $ \xi $ of $x(t)$
for $t\to\infty$." However, I'm not quite sure what "standard arguments" refer to in this context. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me understand this better.

Welcome to MSE. Can you specifiy the dimensions of $f$, $x$?

Thanks for your reply! To clarify, they are $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ and $ x : [0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

Maybe they meant: "at every accumulation point of $x(t)$ for $t \to +\infty$?"

Yes, that's right

But even so, I still don't know what 'standard arguments' actually are

The dynamical system that is being considered here is typically called a gradient system. You can see the reason for this name by applying the chain rule on the time derivative of $f(x(t))$ (here and in the following, I'm assuming that $f$ is at least $\mathcal{C}^1$):
$$
\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t)) = \frac{d}{dx}f(x(t))^\top\frac{d}{dt}x(t) = \nabla f(x(t))^\top\dot{x}(t).
$$
Since $\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t)) = -\lVert\nabla f(x(t))\rVert^2 = -\nabla f(x(t))^\top\nabla f(x(t))$, it is clear that:
$$
\dot{x}(t) = -\nabla f(x(t)),
$$
hence the name.
For gradient systems, it is indeed well known that the accumulation points of the trajectories as $t\rightarrow +\infty$ (called the $\omega$-limit points) are such that $\nabla f(\xi) = 0$. A reference that I personally really like is, e.g., Morris Hirsch and Stephen Smale - Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and Linear Algebra, 1973 (Chapter 9, Section 4). The argument is quite intuitive: it exploits the fact that the value of $f(x(t))$ is decreasing along any trajectory in order to prove that $f(\xi)$ is the greatest lower bound of $\{f(x(t)): t\geq 0\}$, which can then be used to show that $\xi$ is an equilibrium for the gradient system (i.e., $\xi$ is such that $\nabla f(\xi) = 0$).

Edit: per your comment, I'll add more details to the sketch above. The idea to prove that $\xi$ is an equilibrium is to show that any trajectory starting at $\xi$ keeps the energy constant. Formally, suppose that $\{t_n\}\rightarrow\infty$ is a sequence such that $x(t_n)\rightarrow\xi$ and that $\alpha = f(\xi)$. We can obtain the flow $\varphi(\xi,s)$ (i.e., the value of the trajectory starting at $\xi$ at time $s$) by shifting $x(t_n)$, i.e., $x(t_n+s)\rightarrow\varphi(\xi,s)$. But, for the argument above, the value of $f(\varphi(\xi,s))$ is again the greatest lower bound of $\{f(x(t)): t\geq 0\}$, meaning that $f(\varphi(\xi,s)) = \alpha$ for all $s\geq 0$. Thus, $\frac{d}{dt}f(\xi) = 0$, and, since $\frac{d}{dt}f(\xi) = \lVert\nabla f(\xi)\rVert^2$, we obtain $\nabla f(\xi) = 0$.

Can I ask why $f(\xi)$ being the greatest lower bound of ${f(x(t)) : t ≥ 0}$ implies that $\xi$ is an equilibrium point for the gradient system?

@NgọcLê I edited my answer to add more details on that point.

Thank you for helping me understand the problem and providing me with a valuable reference.

The following is a counterexample.
Let $f(x) = |x|^2/2$, $x(t)=e^{-t}x_0$, where $x_0$ is a non-zero element of $\mathbb{R^n}$. Then,

$x(t)$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$ and is bounded. The closure of its image is the closed line segment $[0,x_0]$, connecting the origin to $x_0$. Since the image of $x(\cdot)$ does not contain isolated points, the closure consists of only the accumulation points. Moreover, $\dot{x}(t)=-x(t)$.
$f$ is $C^1$ on the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\nabla f(x)=x$, non-zero on $[0,x_0]$ except at the origin.
A simple calculation gives
$$\frac{d}{dt}f(x(t))=\nabla f(x(t))\cdot\dot{x}(t) = -|x(t)|^2=-|\nabla f(x(t))|^2$$.

